# fastText Quick Start Guide

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, fasttext

I am just reading the recent book called fastText Quick Start Guide and I ran codes in the book.When I ran this code

```
$ cat data/yelp/yelp_review.csv | \
  python parse_yelp_dataset.py \
> data/yelp/yelp_review.v1.csv`
```

It was ok, But when I ran second code,

```
$ cat data/yelp/yelp_review.v1.csv \
| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' \
> data/yelp/yelp_review.v2.csv`
```

it said yelp_review.v1.csv was not found or no such file. Why did it happen? I thought when the first code was ran, that file should be saved in data/yelp as an output file. Can somebody help me understand it?

this is the python code.

```
import csv 
import sys 
w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for row in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin):
       w.writerow([row['stars'], row['text'].replace('\n', '')])
```

Comment: did you try to do `ls data/yelp` and see if the file is there?  you can also run `cat data/yelp/yelp_review.csv |  python parse_yelp_dataset.py` to see what is the output un stdout

Comment: I ran it Gabriel. it was the same.

Comment: what do you mean the same?  `ls data/yelp` contains the v1.csv? what is written into the file?

Comment: Nothing new was written in the folder. The folder has only yelp_review.csv. No output file, yelp_review.v1.csv

Comment: can you add the first rows of the 'data/yelp/yelp_review.csv' ill try to reproduce the error in my machine

Comment: Gabriel, I think it is ok now. The output file was saved when I ran the third time.